# What oauth and Invites do in my google-services.json?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-invites

I use Firebase only for database and ads

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

But generated `google-services.json` has quite a lot of stuff:

[image]

What oauth and Invites do in my google-services.json?

Can I remove it?

There is Firebase Invites service but I've never used it https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/

I don't use Authentication service either, all methods are disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the JSON file doesn't itself *do* anything.  The Google Play services plugin uses it at build time to add data to your app.  If you want to know what exactly the plugin does with your google-services.json file, you can [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).  You don't even need the plugin and the JSON file if you just simulate what the plugin does, directly in your application, by adding the relevant string resources to your app.  That is really the bottom line here - new string resources.  That's it.  And not all of that data actually makes it into your app.

I don't really recommend making changes to your JSON file, as that may confuse the plugin.  I can't think of any way that the information would change the way your app behaves, other than what you'd expect for the products you're using.

Comment: I deleted SHAs https://i.postimg.cc/G9nhYTrs/Screenshot-4.png at project settings (your apps tab) and now json became a little smaller

Comment: Those SHAs were used only by Firebase Dynamic Links, Invites and Auth only (info from tooltips)